why my forward port couldn't work use firewall-cmd

config forward port

firewall-cmd --permanent --add-masquerade
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-forward-port=port=81:proto=tcp:toaddr=127.0.0.1:toport=80
firewall-cmd --reload

now, this is my firwall-cmd.


open a server use: nc -lk 80
use nc -v 127.0.0.1 81 couldn't work, but nc -v 127.0.0.1 80 could work


You may have to use a policy and a rich rule:firewall-cmd --permanent --new-policy=portforward, firewall-cmd --permanent --policy=portforward --add-ingress-zone=HOST, firewall-cmd --permanent --policy=portforward --add-egress-zone=ANY, firewall-cmd --permanent --policy=portforward --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" destination address="127.0.0.0/8" forward-port port="81" protocol="tcp" to-port="80" to-addr="127.0.0.1"', firewall-cmd --reload

@user202311 it work, but why i can't see this forward port by firewall-cmd --list-all or firewall-cmd --list-rich-rules or firewall-cmd --list-forward-ports

use firewall-cmd --list-all-policies could find my forward port, but why --add-forward-port not work

--add-forward-port works for incoming traffic, i.e. for traffic from other IPs. It does not work for traffic from the same host (127.0.0.1).
